# What is the antonym of “bâcler son examen”?

Tags: vocabulaire, antonyme

Can someone tell me please what is the antonym of “bâcler son examen” as in answering the question “How did you do in your exam?”

- *Je l'ai bâclé* (I did fast and poorly)

or

- *I did fast and very well, I nailed it*

How do you say the latter in French?

I know about “j'ai bien fait”, “j'ai excellé” etc. but I'm looking specifically for the slang antonym of “bâclé/manqué”.

I know there is an antonym but I can't remember it anymore.

Comment: It seems you do not have the proper meaning for *bâcler*. A brilliant  student can very well  *bâcler* their exam (they find it very easy...) and pass it with flying colours. If you want to say you've failed it you'd use *rater* or *manquer* (slang *se planter*). *Bâcler* means "rush", "do without care", but not necessarily "fail" - whereas *manquer* means "fail".

Comment: By the way welcome to French Language. You can edit your question to clarify it. Are you asking about success in an exam (antonym of *manquer*) or about doing a job with great care  (antonym of *bâcler*)?

Comment: I'm under the impression the question is fine once we replace all occurences of "bâcler" by "rater", and that this is what OP meant. I'm not editing because maybe there is something more about *bâcler*, as there indeed are antonyms specific to *bâcler* (*torcher* as in, do just as fast, but well).

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks It's probably what OP meant and I told him so but 1) I think edits that change the meaning of the question has to be made by OPs (their responsibility) and 2) if we want the site to keep tidy and serious unclear questions should not be answered but closed until OPs have modified the question. 8 people agreed with my comment but still I was the only one to ask for a close vote.

Comment: Indeed I upvoted your comment and skipped the close vote review. I didn't feel comfortable voting to close a question that seemed so understandable to me. I agreed with 1. until I thought that if OP doesn't come back and edit the right thing in, I'd rather what is left be a good question that's not exactly what he meant, rather than an unclear closed question. (Anthony, do voice what you really meant if I was wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a slang term meaning you brilliantly succeed, you might say:

> J'ai cartonné à mon examen.

This comes from "*faire un carton*" like at a shooting range in a fair.

Comment: À votre avis, le sens est-il altéré si on enlève la préposition ? Merci.

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite J'aurais d'abord pensé que l'expression ne se rencontre pas mais ayant trouvé quelques occurrences de « J'ai cartonné mon examen », le sens y est bien préservé.

Answer (score 2):

*Bâcler quelque chose* means to do something sloppily, without giving it the required level of attention. In someone else's mouth, it's often a criticism implying shoddy results but the primary meaning is related to the level of effort, not the quality of the result.

To refer to the poor result for an exam, in the high register of speech you would say *échouer*, and in everyday language you would typically use *planter*, *se planter*, *rater* as in:

> J'ai échoué à l'examen
>
> J'ai planté mon bac
>
> Je me suis planté dans la deuxième partie de l'examen
>
> J'ai raté mon permis [driver's license exam]

For the particular case of an entrance exam you can also say *être recalé*.

To say the opposite, in the high register of speech you would say *réussir*. Popular antonyms to describe success would be *torcher*, *cartonner*, *assurer*, *déchirer*.

> J'ai torché le bac
>
> J'ai cartonné à l'épreuve orale
>
> J'ai trop bien assuré dans la deuxième partie
>
> J'ai déchiré les maths

These last four terms are slang, but *torcher* is borderline vulgar: the literal meaning is to wipe one's ass, the image behind this being that of someone blazing through the exam as if were toilet paper.

Some slang terms in use by scientific students:

- *majorer* for "coming in with the highest score" (*J'ai majoré l'épreuve de physique du concours*)
- *trivialiser* for "doing well and making it look easy"

(Thanks Random for *déchirer* !)

Comment: What about "J'ai tout déchiré" ? :)

Comment: Merci, ajouté !

Comment: [_Torcher_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/torcher) vous l'entendez comme _dégommer_ ou comme _battre_ ? Ironiquement il a aussi le sens de _bâcler_ en plus. Merci.

Comment: Oui c'est vrai que torcher peut aussi vouloir dire bâcler. Dans le cas d'un examen en temps limité, je l'entends plutôt avec le sens de "très bien réussir, en moins de temps qu'il n'en faut normalement."

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas ce sens influencé par l'anglais du mot torcher

Comment: ref. : _torcher_ (incendier), c'est une influence personnelle, et non pas un sens documenté comme tel. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

"J'ai géré" is often my favorite translation for "I nailed it".

Note that in "J'ai géré", there is no reference to "examen" (the *it* in "I nailed it"). It would be "Je l'ai géré", you can say that but it's often omitted.

Don't forget that "gérer" means "to manage", "to run", "to handle", so of course it's not slang in some contexts.

Slang example :

- Salut mec, t'as apporté de la bière ?
- Ouais ! J'en ai apporté cinq packs !
- Ouah ! T'as géré ! (or "Ouah ! Tu gères !")

Other example :

- Comment s'est passé ton examen ?
- Hum, je pense que j'ai géré, mais on verra !

Comment: Bonus : "Tu gères la fougère !" that means absolutely nothing, the only reason is that it rhymes ("fougère" = "fern"). It is a well known expression, kinda fun.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be scientific *[prépas](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_pr%C3%A9paratoire_aux_grandes_%C3%A9coles)* slang, but we used *“torcher”* to describe exactly that: doing fast and well. Of course, when talking about a full-length exam, in *prépas* it meant *actually completing the copy or at least getting near*, but you could vary well *torcher* a single question or exercise.

Answer (score 1):

en prenant le sens de *bâcler* = *faire **vite** et mal,faire salement* , le contraire est *faire méticuleusement/sérieusement et bien*.

- assurer
- peaufiner
- *blinder* (familier)

Les autres termes qui ne font pas référence à ce concept **vite/pas vite**  ne répondent pas exactement à la question: échouer/réussir, rater, louper, ...

Comment: Vous êtes le seul à avoir exploré l'aspect _méticuleux_ ; le verbe _s'appliquer_ est aussi utile pour dire ça. Merci.